# CUPS - Selecting a driver for a HP printer

Tags: debian, raspbian, cups, printer, hp-printer

I have a HP Photosmart Premium C309g-m printer. There is no matching driver in the list in CUPS installed on my raspberry pi. I tried to run `sudo hp-setup` but the terminal said `sudo: hp-setup: command not found` I just need  to find a suitable driver for my printer.

Background info: My raspberry pi 2 runs raspbian lite (however I installed a gui manually, raspbian is based on debian) and it is connected to the printer over Wi-Fi

**EDIT:** I am following [this](https://www.geekonthepc.com/2016/07/10/guide-make-almost-any-printer-airprint-compatible-with-a-raspberry-pi-in-20-minutes/) guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like HP makes a driver for your device: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index . To use it, you'll need to first install HPLIP from here: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip , selecting your OS (Debian) and running the tool.

Comment: When I run HPLIP it complains that it doesn't know what software to use to run it. What software (or terminal command) do I need to use to run it.

Comment: EDIT: I can use sudo sh (file name)

Comment: Note: if you don't need specifically the latest and greatest version of HPLIP, you can simply say `apt install hplip` - it's in the standard Debian repository, and so probably in raspbian too.