# HPLIP: Some packages not installing

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cups, hplip

I installed HPLIP on my raspberry pi to use CUPS as per [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511669/cups-selecting-a-driver-for-a-hp-printer/511673#511673) but some packages are simply not installing. I have tried:`sudo apt-get -f install hplip`, `sudo apt-get install qt4-default qt4-designer qt4-doc qt4-dev-tools python-qt4` and the same for PYQT5, `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` and countless other things. Does anyone know what to do. My latest string (after doing all of the above and more for nearly 2 hours) is this: 
**couldn't get the code snippet mode to work - don't know why.**

### MISSING DEPENDENCIES

Following dependencies are not installed. HPLIP will not work if all REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some of the HPLIP features will not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not installed.
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional
pyqt5-dbus           gui_qt5              OPTIONAL
pyqt5                gui_qt5              REQUIRED
Do you want to install these missing dependencies (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y

### INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES

note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: pyqt5 (PyQt 5- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))

### INSTALL MISSING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCIES

note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing OPTIONAL dependency for option 'gui_qt5': pyqt5-dbus (PyQt 5 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt5)

### CHECKING FOR NETWORK CONNECTION

Network connection present.

### RUNNING PRE-PACKAGE COMMANDS

su -c "dpkg --configure -a" (Pre-depend step 1)
su -c "apt-get install -f" (Pre-depend step 2)
su -c "apt-get update" (Pre-depend step 3)
OK

### DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION

Running 'su -c "apt-get install --force-yes -y gtk2-engines-pixbuf"'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'su -c "apt-get install --force-yes -y python-pyqt5"'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Running 'su -c "apt-get install --force-yes -y python-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5"'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: A required dependency 'pyqt4-dbus (PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4)' is still missing.
error: A required dependency 'pyqt4 (PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))' is still missing.

### RUNNING POST-PACKAGE COMMANDS

OK

### RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES

error: A required dependency 'pyqt4-dbus (PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4)' is still missing.
error: A required dependency 'pyqt4 (PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without these dependencies.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.```